# Coolite EXT GridPanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, extjs

I'm new in using Extjs Library , I want to use GridPanel but I don't know how to use it with aspnet ,

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please don't use Hello word, when post any question, you can use Hi, this is my request to you. Thanks

Comment: OK , as you like , But can I ask Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this sample from extjs web :
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/ArrayGrid/Simple/